# how to know linux server reboot reason

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6.2

I've a linux server previously it was on physical machine. Physical machine was getting stuck and i had to reboot it. I shifted it to xen vm. After shifting to Xen vm its now rebooting. Its doing the same behavior like physical machine just difference is that physical machine was getting stuck and i had to reboot it and vm is rebooting automatically.

I want to trace the actual fault how can I ?

It is already 0 in /proc/sys/kernel/panic and I've installed fresh OS just shifted website data to VM

Comment: Look in the log files in /var/log for anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some useful information on the virtual console, but it sounds like your system is set to automatically reboot when the kernel panics.  You can disable this by running this as root:

```
 echo "0" > /proc/sys/kernel/panic
```

You wrote:

> I shifted it to xen vm.

What exactly did you do?  Did you do a backup-and-restore of the exact same system/image, or did you re-install a new CentOS 6.2 for the new Xen VM?  Using the same system/image might have brought across a bad kernel and/or driver, but a fresh install to the VM should not have any of those same problems.

Comment: It is already 0 in /proc/sys/kernel/panic
and I've installed fresh OS just shifted website data to VM.